# Unable to save because of 'another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this Controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/person/test/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Test(Guid id)
{
    var person = this.PersonManager.Get(id);

    person.Lastname = "Jameson";

    this.PersonManager.Save(person);

    return Ok(true);
}
```

Deep underneath this save method is called:

```
protected void Add<T>(T source, MyEntities context, bool isNew) where T : class
{
    if (isNew)
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(source);
    }
    else
    {
        var entry = context.Entry(source);
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            context.Set<T>().Attach(source);

            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error when executing this:

> Attaching an entity of type 'Model.Person' failed because another
>   entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This
>   can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an
>   entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as
>   appropriate.

It occurs on the `context.Set<T>().Attach(source)` line.

PS: This is a followup/spin off of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289369/second-call-to-same-dbcontext-causes-error-dbcontext-has-been-disposed/34290947#34290947).

Comment: Why is your entity detached in this case, if you load it using Get? Looks like it's loaded and kept in DbContext, so when you attach it again it conflicts with original copy of itself. Also do you dispose context between Get and Save operations?

Comment: @raderick: Good question. The question this is a followup off was regarding an unexpected Dispose. It may be the cause of this issue.

Comment: you should definitely track entity state of your person entity from loading to saving again, looks like at some point it's detached but also kept in the same context, so when you attach it again this issue happens.

Comment: can you check `context.person.Local` to see if have one person object which have the same primary with the updated person object?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (!context.Set<T>().Local.Contains(source))
 {
    context.Set<T>().Attach(source);
 }

context.Entry(source).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's basically a different way of doing the same thing. So, also the same error.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Isn't this code only missing an else to handle the case where the object already is attached, and then you use the method `Add`? In any case, for anyone looking for a solution, see if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705569/using-the-entrytentity-currentvalues-setvalues-is-not-updating-collections